# How would you make an diagonal checkerboard in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

So, I know how to a checkerboard patter (I'm using some image files for each tile, and just have a few lines that alternate the placement of them, so it final board appears checkered). Now, I would like to make a board that is checkered, but diagonal. I have 1:2 height:width diamond tile images for each tile, but I can't come up with a good method to place them so they appear properly on the board. So far, I have tried both GridLayout and FloatLayout to little success. I'm sure there are many way to do this, but I'm struggling with it.

[End product should look similar to this (the board, not pieces or anything)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fnb8.jpg)

How would you do it?

Best?

Comment: You should add some example code that you have tried and elaborate on why you've had "little success"

Answer (score 0):

Do it with GridLayout in default orientation and rotate the layout as it's shown in this [example](https://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__canvas__rotation__py.html). If you want to do chess-like something(clickable figurines on diagonal checkerboard), I think the same should work for figures keeping them functional.

Comment: So, I have tried it this way, and it rotates in the z- and y- axis just fine. However, I'm attempting to make the bird more isometrics, so the top needs to be tilted toward -x and the bottom toward +X. However, when I do this, the top and bottom get cut off and I see just a band on the middle of the board. I think this is a field of view issue but I have had no luck in addressing it.

Comment: I realize I didn't specify that I wanted it rotated in all three direction. That was my bad, but if you have any advice, it would be more than welcome!

Comment: Yeah, should have known this from the image. My bad, sorry. Well, I think kivy doesn't target 3D primarily. However, there is an [example](https://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__3Drendering__main__py.html) for 3D. Check `update_glsl()` and `setup_scene()`.